# Correct usage of visibility properties in python such as object variables and methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with python for a short while and want to be clear on how to use python visibility properties such as objects and methods.

I know that 
`self.any` is going to be public
`self._any` (an underscore) is going to be protected
`self.__any` (double underscores) is going to be private

I can understand the meaning but I have one doubt in using `self._any`

Protected in PHP will be possible in only parent and child class where public is not.

But in python I can call protected from everywhere too.

Let say:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self._any = 'Anything'

Test()._any # 'Anything'
```

Pls help explain this or give some examples regarding protected objects and methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a single and a double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Answer (score 1):

In python private and protected method are only concepts. The implementation of protected method is only provided for development help, but it's not really a protected method as we can still access its value. And it's especially true for private method. See links under your post.